# Open mapping theorem using wikipedia proof

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f: U \to \mathbb{C}$ be a non constant analytic function on an
>   open connected set $U$. Then $f$ is an open set, this means that for
>   any open set $S \subset U$, we have that $f(S)$ is open.

So basically our aim is to show that if $S$ is an open set, then $$f(S) = \{f(z)~|~z \in S\}$$ is an open set. So by the definition of open set, if we can show for each $f(z) \in f(S)$, there exists some $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B(f(z),\epsilon) \subset f(S)$, then we are done. It means that every point in $f(S)$ has a neighborhood which is also in $f(S)$.

We know that for any $w_0 \in f(S)$, there will exist $z_0 \in S$ such that $w_0 = f(z_0)$. Since $S$ is open, we can find $d>0$ such that $B(z_0,d) \subset S$. Consider the function $g(z) = f(z) - w_0$ and note that $z_0$ is a zero of $g(z)$.

Do note that $g(z)$ is not constant and analytic and by the identity theorem, we can always decrease the radius of $d$ such that $B(z_0,\epsilon_1)$ contains no zeros except for $z_0$. So there is only one zero inside $B(z_0,\epsilon_1)$.

Since $B(z_0,\epsilon_1)$ is a compact set, and $|g(z)|$ is continuous on $B(z_0,\epsilon_1)$, we thus have by the Extreme Value Theorem that 
the minimum of $|g(z)|$ is achieved somewhere on the boundary, and that $|g(z)| \geq e$ for all $z \in B(z_0,\epsilon_1)$.

We then create a open ball around $w_0$, call it $\beta(w_0,e)$ where $e$ is the minimum value of $|g(z)|$. Now for any $w_1 \in \beta(w_0,e)$, and for any $z$ on the boundary of $B(z_0,\epsilon_1)$, we have  $$|g(z)| \geq e > |w_0-w_1|$$

By Rouche's Theorem, $g(z)$ and $g(z) + (w_0-w_1)$ have the same number of zeros in $B(z_0,\epsilon_1)$. **(Is it 1 zero?)**

Thus, $g(z) + (w_0-w_1) = 0 \Rightarrow f(z) = w_1$ **(I do not understand how this step will lead to the conclusion of the proof, any help will be appreciated.)**

I think i lack the understanding of how counting zeros can lead to the set $f(S)$ is open. Spent a few hours but still did not develop the idea.